# Drupal Commerce Line Item Revisions

Tags: commerce, nodes

Has anyone seen a module capable of providing line item revisions? I am calculating the cost of a custom line item type via rules. It is essentially a booking and may need to be altered in the future.

I am therefore looking for some information from anyone who may have had a similar issue? This is what I need.

1. Every time I recalculate the price of a line item on an order to create a new revision.
2. Always display the latest revision to the user.
3. Provide a view showing other revisions in the admin panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line item entity doesn't have revisions, so you would need to add this for all line items. Which means, you need to alter some of the very core of Drupal Commerce. It's possible, but maybe it would be better to store bookings in a custom table and save a reference on the line item instead.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your help. Do you know any module or way to view order revision data? Or would I have to create a view for that.

Comment: @ben Creating a View would probably be the easiest solution. I don't believe there is any functionality for doing this yet.